# How to solve wave equation with Robin boundary condition?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

The question I am stuck on is from Strauss (Exercise 4.3.10):

> Solve the wave equation with Robin boundary conditions under the assumption that $a_0+a_l<-a_0a_ll$ holds.

I know that this condition means there is one negative eigenvalue $\lambda_0$ and the rest are positive. I should be able to compute $\lambda_0$ from
$$\tanh(\sqrt{\lambda_0}l)=\frac{-(a_0+a_l)\sqrt{\lambda_0}}{\lambda_0+a_0a_l}$$
and the corresponding eigenfunction from
$$X_0(x)=\cosh(\sqrt{\lambda_0}x)+\frac{a_0}{\sqrt{\lambda_0}} \sinh(\sqrt{\lambda_0}x)$$
but I don't know how to do this. Once I find $X_0(x)$ I believe I can substitute it in to
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty X_n(x) T_n(t)$$
along with $T_0(t)=A_0 \cosh(\sqrt{|\lambda_0|}ct)+B_0 \sinh(\sqrt{|\lambda_0|}ct)$ to get a solution. But I have no clue if this is correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the full problem, along with what the constants $a_0, a_l, l$ mean